# Does Python Pandas to_csv have max number of rows?

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I am attempting to export a text file into a csv. The file is very large (1.6 million rows) tab delimited file. When I export the file using to_csv it only exports 1048576 rows. Is there a maximum amount of rows that to_csv will export?

should I export the data in a different way? I would really like to be able to get it into a csv.

here is an example of my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

from pandas import Series, DataFrame

pathDataEDM = "C:/Users/FILE.txt"

dataEDM = pd.read_csv(pathDataEDM, sep="\t")

dataEDM.to_csv(os.path.join(ExportDir),index=False)
```

Comment: Have you verified that the data were _read_ correctly? E.g. does `dataEDM.info()` report the right number of rows?

Comment: Like alexis, I would check for a format/parsing error near where the export stops. For instance, if you start exporting 48576 rows into the text file, do you get 1048576 exported rows, or 1000000?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas doesn't have a limit. However, most tools you use to open csv files like LibreOffice calc or excel can only display a maximum of  1048576 rows.
To prove the point, try `print(df)` and all the 1.6 million rows would be displayed by pandas

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a maximum (since it is not documented and 1.6 million is quite low for the maximum).

You can try specifying the following optional arguments (see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)):

> **chunksize** : *int or None* 
>   rows to write at a time
>
> **compression** : *string, optional*
>   a string representing the compression to use in the output file,
>   allowed values are `‘gzip’, ‘bz2’, ‘xz’`, only used when the first
>   argument is a filename